# Data exporting from Financial Times

Tags: matlab, web-scraping, export, financial

I am new at `Matlab` and I am currently working with financial data exporting from financial times website. I would like to know how can I get, for example, share price forecast information from this page

http://markets.ft.com/research/Markets/Tearsheets/Forecasts?s=DIS:NYQ

```
High    +34.7 % 85.00
Med     +15.7 % 73.00
Low      -9.6 % 57.00
```

And save this information as a variables.

Comment: Just these six numbers? Manually or automatically?

Comment: automatically, because it would be so great, if I could read ticker list in string "AssetList" and then automatically make this algorithm to all shares in this list and then create variables which then could be used for analysis. Thank you

Comment: Perhaps ditch Matlab and use R's quantmod: http://www.quantmod.com/. Also there is a Matlab trading toolbox.

Comment: Are you sure that you wan to [scrape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) that particular site? There are numerous web APIs available to download near realtime market data in lightweight formats, e.g., CSV, XML, JSON, etc. For example [this](http://dev.markitondemand.com) and [this](http://webdlabs.com/2011/10/live-stock-quotes-in-json-or-xml-format-at-no-cost/). These in conjunction with Matlab's [`urlread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/urlread.html) might work. Re `urlread`, be sure to read [this](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/expanding-urlreads-capabilities/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using [`urlread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/urlread.html) and [`regexpi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexpi.html):

```
% Create URL string and read in HTML
ftbaseurl = 'http://markets.ft.com/research/Markets/Tearsheets/Forecasts?s=';
ticksym = 'DIS:NYQ';
s = urlread([ftbaseurl ticksym]);

% Create pattern string for regular expression matching
trspan = '<tr><td class="text"><span class="';
tdspan1 = '</span></td><td><span class="\w\w\w color ">'; % \w\w\w matchs pos or neg
matchstr1 = '(?<percent>[\+|\-]*\d+.\d+)'; % percent: match (+or-)(1+ digits).(1+ digits)
tdspan2 = ' %</span></td><td>';
matchstr2 = '(?<price>\d+\.\d\d)</td></tr>'; % price: match (1+ digits) . 2 digits
pat = [trspan 'high">High' tdspan1 matchstr1 tdspan2 matchstr2 '|' ...
       trspan 'med">Med' tdspan1 matchstr1 tdspan2 matchstr2 '|' ...
       trspan 'low">Low' tdspan1 matchstr1 tdspan2 matchstr2];

% Match patterns in HTML, case insensitive, put results in struct array
forecasts = regexpi(s,pat,'names');
```

The result is a 1-by-3 [struct array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) where each element has two fields, `'percent'` and `'price'`, that each contain strings extracted by the regular expression parser. For example

```
>> forecasts(3)

ans = percent: '-10.3'
        price: '57.00'

>> str2double(forecasts(3).percent)

-10.3000
```

I'll leave it to you to convert the strings to numbers (note that financial software usually stores prices in integer cents (or what ever the lowest denomination is) rather than floating point dollars [to avoid numerical issues](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/NUM04-J.+Do+not+use+floating-point+numbers+if+precise+computation+is+required)) and to turn this into a general function. Here's some [more information on regular expressions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html) in Matlab.

My comment above still stands. This is very inefficient. You're downloading the entire webpage HTML and parsing it in order to find a few small bits of data. This is fine if this doesn't update very often or if you don't need it to be very fast. Also, this scheme is fragile. If the Financial Times updates their website, it may break the code. And if you try downloading their regular webpages very often they may also have means of blocking you.

Comment: Thank you, horchler! But is there any opportunity to use Markit Data API in matlab? I know that FT use all data from there.

Comment: See [this](http://dev.markitondemand.com/#doc). I think you'd just need to craft the correct URL string for what you want, do a `urlread` of that string, and then parse the result (with `regexp`, an XML parser, etc.). I have no idea if they support the kind of forecast data that you gave as an example though. I have no real experience in that.